# Showing users current location with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I am currently trying to show the users current location like the way google maps shows you as a blue dot when you are viewing it. I have got this code from a similar enough question however I keep getting the error as follows:

> map.html:120 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

This shows for my closing script tag.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">© MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = L.map('map').setView([54.597286, -5.930120], 13);
      L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=uBY6ahbkytE9SXI2vHOw', {
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        minZoom: 1,
        attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">© MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
        crossOrigin: true
      }).addTo(map);

      var point = [54.578087, -5.982472];
      var myMarker = L.marker(point);
      myMarker.addTo(map);
      myMarker.bindPopup(
        '<b>No Limits</b><div><img style = "width:100%" src="https://www.nolimits.fitness/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/PERSONAL-TRAINING.jpg" alt="image"/></div>', {
          minWidth: 256
        }
      );

      function onLocationFound(e) {
              var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

              L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
                  .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

              L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
          }

          function onLocationError(e) {
              alert(e.message);
          }

          map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
          map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

          map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16})

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing "}" that is causing the error message, your `initMap()` function is not properly closed.

Comment: This alone wouldn't help since `initMap()` is never called. It's execution is usually fired with `body` element `onload` event: `<body onload="initMap()">
`.

Comment: That's not relevant to the error itself, may be there's more code to follow, where at some point that function is called, an equally valid solution.

Comment: Perfect! Stupid mistake on my behalf as that was old code i thought id removed. Code works as intended now. Thanks alot

Comment: so after testing a few miles from my current location at the time that was working... it seems that the code still shows my original location and not my new location? I dont seem to set specific coordinates for my original location however? any ideas? Thanks again